# How to set vertical alignment as center responsively in div

Tags: html, css

How do I center .arrow inside .prev & .next vertically & responsive to the height of .mySlides as it varies based on content. I've tried adjusting position, top, transform, margin-top, line-height and can't get the result I'm looking for. Here is the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/t8ap0gvz/4/

```
.prev {
grid-area: 1 / 1 / 4 / 1;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 40px;
opacity: 0.5;
background: yellow;
border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;
border: 1px solid red;
left: 10%;
position:relatve
}

.next {
grid-area: 4 / 4 / 1 / 3;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 40px;
opacity: 0.5;
background: yellow;
border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
border: 1px solid red;
position:relatve
}


.arrow {
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: position:relative to next /prev and remove default margin from p

Comment: I added position relative to .prev & .next with top: 50% and updated .arrow to position relative and this did not solve my issue. where is default margin?

Comment: no need to add any top:50% or change position of arrow. Keep your code like you posted here and simply add `position:relatve` to nex/prev (the container of arrow) .. and the default margin is on arrow which is a P element

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried applying different margins to both .arrow and p{}. I've edited the positions in my question for you to see - but it didn't solve my issue. Do I have it wrong still?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/214kyfj3/

Comment: @TemaniAfif your edits cause .arrow to not be centered horizontally and .prev has been shift to the right and is no longer aligned to the left side of .slideshow-container

Comment: you arrow wasn't centred horizontally initially .. to do this use the same trick like you did with top ... for the shift, you have left:10% on the code remove it: https://jsfiddle.net/6cm98vef/